# How to await Subject.next

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Suppose I have a subscription like this:

`mySubject$.subscribe(async inp => await complexFunction(inp))`

Suppose that `mySubject$` is a Subject that I own. I need a way to do this somehow:

`await mySubject$.next(inp)`

so that I can wait for the `complexFunction` to complete.

I tried to create a custom Subject implementation for this, but it does not seem to be easy. Maybe I'm missing somethink and it's actually simple.

What are my options here?

**Update:**

Based on the idea that rxjs APIs should accept Promises, I tried the code below. It **does not work**, so again, I'm out of ideas.

```
function rigObservable<T>(observable: Observable<T>) {
    let resolve;
    return {
        awaiter: new Promise<void>(res => resolve = res),
        observable: observable.pipe(tap(() => resolve()))
    };
}

fdescribe('test', () => {
    it('should work', async () => {
        const subject = new Subject<string>();
        const wrapper = rigObservable(subject);
        let testValue;
        wrapper.observable.subscribe(inp => of(inp).pipe(delay(1000), tap(t => testValue = t)).toPromise());
        subject.next('text');
        await wrapper.awaiter;
        expect(testValue).toEqual('text');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. It's not very simple, but it's not hard to understand. Below is not a complete implementation, you should add cleanup and checks, but it works.

```
function awaitNext(testFunc) {
    return async function() {
        Subject.prototype['saved_subscribe'] = Subject.prototype.subscribe;
        Subject.prototype['saved_next'] = Subject.prototype.next;
        Subject.prototype['promiseArray'] = [];
        Subject.prototype['subscribe'] = function (n, e, c) {
            let wrappedN, wrappedE, wrappedC;
            wrappedN = v => {
                const p = n(v);
                if (p instanceof Promise) this.promiseArray.push(p);
            }
            wrappedE = v => {
                const p = e(v);
                if (p instanceof Promise) this.promiseArray.push(p);
            }
            wrappedC = v => {
                const p = c(v);
                if (p instanceof Promise) this.promiseArray.push(p);
            }
            return this.saved_subscribe(wrappedN, wrappedE, wrappedC);
        } as any;
        Subject.prototype['next'] = function (v) {
            this.saved_next(v);
            return Promise.all(this.promiseArray).then(() => this.promiseArray = []);
        }
        return await testFunc();
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
it('works', awaitNext(async () => {
        const subject = new Subject<string>();
        let actualValue;
        subject.subscribe(v => of(v).pipe(delay(2000), tap(t => actualValue = t)).toPromise());
        await subject.next('foo');
        expect(actualValue).toEqual('foo');
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure of your intent, but maybe something like this would work:

```js
const source$ = mySubject$.pipe(
    mergeMap(inp => complexFunction(inp))
);

source$.subscribe(
    value => console.log('received value from complexFunction', value)
);
```

`source$` is an observable that will emit the result of `complexFunction()` each time `mySubject$` emits.

Comment: Would not work, in this case the log would happen instantly, not after complexFunction completes. (Assuming complexFunction is async. In my question I wrote: ```mySubject$.subscribe(async inp => await complexFunction(inp))```. The subscriber function is async.)

Comment: Did you try this?  It will only emit after complexFunction emits!

Comment: I'll give it a try

Comment: I should have used `mergeMap` instead of `switchMap`. Here's a working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-yqtw9j?devtoolsheight=60&file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=100) demo.

Comment: I checked this more in-depth. I don't think this concept works in my usecase. I don't have control over complexFunction, I can't just place it in a mergeMap. I only have control over the Subject.
I guess this would work based on the idea that rxjs APIs accept Promises. Based on this I add an example test code to my question. In principle that should work, but it does not.